# VBA: Horizontal and vertical movement using loops for dynamic ranges

Tags: vba, loops

I've to calculate average or sum or standard deviation or.. of 10 entries in a column say D3:D12 and populate row till Z column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr6E2.png)

part 1:-

```
Sub hg()
Dim i As Long
Range("D13").Select
Do Until i = 20
i = i + 1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

This I've coded. Is there any method easy to drag side ways ?

I need to continue this again in 28th row, 43rd row & so on with 15 rows difference.

What I could think of is adding 
Part two:-

```
Sub hg()
Dim i As Long
Range("D13").Select
Do Until i = 20
i = i + 1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
Loop
Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 15, ActiveCell.Column - 20).Select
End Sub
```

Which is directing to 28th row but not working to populate along this row. I'm unable to direct vertical movement.

I'm no serious coder but very interested to learn. Please help to populate along the vertical direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Offset() and loop stepping 15 rows at every iteration

```
Sub hg()
    Dim i As Long`enter code here`

    For i = 13 To 43 Step 15 '<--| change 43 to your actual last row to populate with formula
        Range("D1:Z1").Offset(i-1).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Final code I'm now successfully using is 
    
Sub hg()
Dim i As Long
Range("D13").Select
Do Until i = 10
i = i + 1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"
Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 15, 4).Select
Loop
End Sub

Comment: You are warmly encouraged to avoid avoid Select/Selection/ActiveXXX pattern and use fully qualified range references. Furthermore Copy/Paste is an expensive operation: you may not perceive it with little data or operations but you may want to get into the habit of using Value property to copy values between ranges or write formulas directly.  Try my code and let me know